# Is instance context typing possible?

Tags: typescript

Before I make a feature request, is it possible for TypeScript to tell the type of an instance's property based on what methods have been called in the scope? For example in this code only `readAsDataURL()` has been called on `const fileReader` so `fileReader.result` must be a string but its still type `string | ArrayBuffer`

```
public blobToDataURL(data: Blob): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.addEventListener('error', event => {
        reject(fileReader.error);
    });
    fileReader.addEventListener('load', event => {
        resolve(fileReader.result as string);
    });
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(data);
  });
}
```

If you remove `as string` you get

> Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible. Even if this feature existed, it would likely not be syntactically retroactive - the method call probably would never apply to a *previous* reference to the variable.